# issue on hosting MVC5 application on IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7

I am developing one application in MVC5 framework visual studio 2013 but when deploying on IIS7 it shows directory as below image.why it is happen I don't understand . IIS server having .Net framework 4.0 is installed and sql server 2008 R2.[image]

Please give some suggestion on that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure TestDeployNC is defined as an Application Scope in IIS. Right-click on the directory in IIS Manager and choose "Convert to Application".

Comment: I am try that one but same issue is there.(Thanks for reply)